# Anime Strike just got absorbed into Amazon Prime. What high profile series just opened up there?

Tags: streaming-sites

I just learned that Anime Strike just got absorbed into Amazon Prime! I just watched the first episode of *Made in Abyss*. For Amazon Prime members like me, who were too stubborn to pay extra for Anime Strike, what series which were not available on other streaming services are now available?

Note that I live in the USA and subscribe to Crunchyroll and Funimation.

Comment: Could you be more specific on "*other streaming services*"? Is it US-only, or..? Otherwise, I think it's too broad (My first impression is global including Japan). Also, is the question only about what addition comes from Anime Strike (as per title), or also comparing other streaming sites (as per question body)?

Comment: Yes, USA.  I live in the US and subscribe to both Crunchyroll and Funimation. Also, I don't know outside the USA what Amazon Prime Video makes available. For me, though, my Amazon Prime subscription just became a lot more valuable.

Comment: I think you have to mention that info on the question. Crunchyroll's contents depend on the country, and Funimation is not available in my country.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to search again. The first time I searched on their site with "prime video anime", there were 400 result pages.  I just searched again, and it is giving me 20 pages of "most relevant results". Here are some series that stuck out for me:

- *Land of the Lustrous*
- *Re:CREATORS*
- *Welcome to the Ballroom*
- *Dive!!*
- *The Great Passage*
- *Made in Abyss* (retyped here so they in one spot)

These are recent series I don't remember being available on Crunchyroll or Funimation in the USA.

// 6 Jan 18
A new YouTube video posted today which includes mention of a lot of good Amazon Prime titles, even ones not super-recent.  See [Ding-Dong! Anime Strike is Dead. What Now?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YIsBsWjOB58)